# #1467 - Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Tags: java, mysql, auto-increment

I was trying to create a new object and this error appeared:

java.sql.sqlexception failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

So I went to the phpMyAdmin to create the object there and the same showed up:

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1467 - Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

then I clicked on edit, and it was there:

```
INSERT INTO `reservation`.`room` (`idroom`, `number`, `floor`, `description`, `characteristics`, `cost`, `status`, `type`) VALUES (NULL, '114', '3', 'ss', 'ss', '550.00', 'Available', 'ss')
```

(idroom is supposed to be auto-incremented.)

I already read other posts where they say I have to put this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

but I have no idea where to put that. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement is wrong. Since `idroom` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`; you must not include it in the column list on your insert command. Your insert statement should look like below. Notice that I have removed `idroom` column from insert column list and not passing `NULL` as well in value list.

```
INSERT INTO `reservation`.`room` (`number`, `floor`, `description`, 
`characteristics`, `cost`, `status`, `type`) 
VALUES ('114', '3', 'ss', 'ss', '550.00', 'Available', 'ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this problem and searched, and didn't find anything. Then the following worked for me; I guess it might work for your problem. Thx.

```
1st:
-delete (before backup)->all data from your database.
-try to run your Java program again, or any program you want.
```

> If it fails then go to 2nd.

```
2nd: 
- backup all data from your table
- delete table completely 
- create table again; example shown below:
```

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
    `f_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `l_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone_num` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
ALTER TABLE `users`
MODIFY `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```